# Hashmap containKey() method check

Tags: java, hashmap

When I call containsKey(value) it returns false when the key is in the map. I would appreciate it if someone could check my code!

I have already tried printing out they key and hashmap toString method and they Key is in the map.

```
    HashMap<IdentifierInterface, T> hm = new HashMap<IdentifierInterface, T>();

    public T getMemory(String v) {

        if(hm.containsKey(v)){

            return hm.get(v);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Hashcode and Equals methods in `IdentifierInterface`:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return identifier.toString().hashCode();
}


public boolean equals(Object toCompare) {
    if (toCompare instanceof Identifier) {
        if (toCompare.hashCode() == this.hashCode()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The expected result is true and actual is false in getMemory().

Comment: What is the `identifier` in `return identifier.toString().hashCode();`?

Comment: What is IdentifierInterface and what values are available in map. And it'snot good practice to consider two objects equal if they have same hashcode value.

Comment: You've defined a `Map` which has keys of type `IdentifierInterface` and you're checking to see if it's got a key of type `String` in it.  That's never going to be true.

Comment: good catch @JBNizet – a HashMap with keys of type `IdentifierInterface` will never contain a key of type `String`, so always false result. separately, `getMemory()` can be simplified to just return the result of `hm.get(v)` – it will either be null or whatever matched, so just do: `public T getMemory(String v) { return hm.get(v); }`

Comment: Your equals method probably shouldn't actually just look at the hash codes; it should almost certainly compare the actual identifier strings and check if they are `equals` to each other.

Comment: yes I realize that it would never be correct. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HashMap` keys are of type `IdentifierInterface`, but you're calling `containsKey(String)`.

In your `equals()` you however use `instanceof Identifier` which will always return `false` when a `String` is passed in.

So turn your `String` into an `IdentifierInterface` (or make the keys `Strings` instead).

Comment: Thank you this makes sense!!